# Reading InputStream from webservice response

Tags: java, web-services, stream, inputstream

What I am trying to do seems to be a quite simple thing, get an InputStream from a Jersey webservice which is returned from a class RestResponse. But I don't get the stream to my client:

```
public class RestResponse {
    private InputStream responseStream;

    public RestResponse(InputStream responseBodyStream) throws IOException{     
        this.responseStream = responseBodyStream;   
        //here I can get the stream contents from this.responseStream
    }

    public InputStream getResponseStream() throws IOException { 
        //here stream content is empty, if called from outside
        //only contains content, if called from constructor
        return this.responseStream;
    }
}

public class HttpURLConnectionClient{

    public RestResponse call(){
        try{
            ....

            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            RestResponse rr = new RestResponse(in); 
        }finally{
           in.close(); <- this should be the suspect
        }
    }
}


    RestResponse rr = httpURLConnectionClient.call()//call to some url
    rr.getResponseStream(); //-> stream content is empty
```

Any ideas, what I am missing? Is is not possible to just pipe the stream through?

Comment: Are you trying to do anything with the stream other than return it?

Comment: For now, I am just trying to get it piped to System.out. I omitted that part. But this is successful where I indicated that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain types of `InputStream` can only be read once in Java.  Based on your comment above, it appears that you are using the `InputStream` when you pipe it to `System.out`.  Try commenting out the call to `System.out` and see if you can access your `InputStream`.  Also make sure that the stream is not being consumed anywhere else in the code before the point where you need it.

**Update:**

It appears that your actual problem was being caused by closing the `InputStream` before you got a chance to use it.  So the solution is to keep the stream open until you need it, and close it afterwards.

Typically, it is not a good design practice to open a stream and keep it open for a long time, because then the underlying resource won't be available to anyone else who needs it.  So you should open the stream, and consume it only when you actually need it.

Comment: I checked not to have any consumption of this stream before. The only time I pipe to System.out is at the very end, on the client. But without success. I suppose, only setting `this.responseStream = responseBodyStream;` is not consuming the stream.

Comment: Wait a minute...how did it succeed with `System.out` but fail if you try before that?

Comment: Well, if I do the `System.out` in the constructor of RestResponse, it gives me the stream content. If I do `System.out` later than that (e.g. in `getResponseStream()`, it fails.

Comment: This sounds like the stream is being closed.  Can you post the code surrounding the call to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, added more code. I see what you mean. I close the InputStream as I did before, when I just returned plain text from the same stream.

Comment: Ok, that works now. Thanks a lot for your patience. Could you update your response about the relevant point?